# Sharing AWS S3 files publicly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, file-sharing

I am working on a project where I can generate shareable links for users which will expire after some time also link can be regenerated.
I have tried all the solutions in web to generate signed urls but none of them is working for me.

I have used node **aws-sdk** 's getSignedUrl method and other third party packages but none of them is working

when i try to access file via **S3**'s link it retun an error 
[image: error]

here is the code I am using

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: ID,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    secretAccessKey: SECRET,
    region:region
});

const uploadFile = (filePath) => {
    // Read content from the file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `Share-TEST/${Date.now()}`,
        ACL:"private",
        ContentType:"image/jpeg",
        Body: fileContent
    };
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(data.Location);


        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: data.Key, Expires: 60}, function (err, url) {
            console.log(err,url)
          })
    });
};

uploadFile("/path/to/file")
```

and the url generated is link

> https://bucket-name.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com/Share-TEST/15852504924-1?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=111111111111111/22222222/region-name/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=202033333416Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=333333333&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host'

Please help me with some code or links

Comment: Your client's GET HTTP request needs to have a host header. Does it? Its value would be something like bucket-name.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com. Any chance your client or a proxy is stripping the host header?

Comment: @jarmod can you provide some proper links, docs or example to implement this?